# Controlling Number Of Async Operations

Tags: scala, slick

I am using scala/slick for a little project,
I need do parse something and insert them to db, but parser is too fast so when I insert parsed values asynchronously via slick thread pool just becomes full and I am getting `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef`.

Is there any way to get how many tasks are there in queue and throttle the parser using that information?

Comment: Suggest you use an actor (Akka) to insert into db. On completion of the Future that you get back from the parser, you should pass the result to your actor. Its message queue should take care of your problem.

Comment: Although I would use Akka in almost any case like that as @Phasmid suggested , it worth to look at [fs2\scalaz-stream](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) lib, which could make some producer-consumer buffering for you.